# error "cannot resolve simbol gson"

Tags: android-studio

hola cuando importo esta libreria en android studio
import com.google.gson.Gson;
me dice que cannot resolve simbol gson
La busque con el sdk manage en la parte de google y no la encuentro , que puede ser?
Dejo el build.gradle no se si tenga que ver con el sdk.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "aplicacionesmoviles.tp"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que añadir la dependencia a Gson en tu `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
  //Resto de dependencias de tu proyecto
  compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
}
```

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Esta la opcion de @Puas o tambien puedes importar el .jar y agregarlo en Proyect Structure en Android Studio. Te recomiendo esta pagina para descargar librerias: https://javalibs.com/
Saludos